# I want search functionality in yii

Tags: search, yii

my code is here for searching in index.php

```
Search: <?php echo CHtml::textField(
        'search', 
        '',
        array(
            'style'=>'width:150px',
            'placeholder'=>Yii::t('app', 'User name...'),
            'onchange'=>'$.fn.yiiGridView.update("user-grid", {
                data: { "Users[username]": $(this).val() 
                    }
            });
            return false;'
        )); ?>
```

Its desinging
[image]

Its properly searching username
now i wnat to search first_name and last_name in this(same)box 
plz help me what to do changes for that

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data: { "Users[username]": $(this).val() }
```

should become

```
data: { "Users[username]": $(this).val(), "Users[first_name]": $(this).val(), "Users[last_name]": $(this).val() }
```

and maybe you should add `AND` or `OR` to your query